# ¿Como puedo modificar un resource de tipo Json en C#?

Tags: c#, json

tengo un Json guardado en las propiedades del proyecto, en el cual guardo informacion sobre el sistema, mi problema es que solo puedo leer el archivo pero no puedo ditarlo ¿ Alguien sabe como puedo editar el Json? el archivo Json esta guardado en la carpeta default que crea el Properties.Resources

```
//Leo el Json
byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.Json;
        
string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);

// intento de guardado
if (!Guardado)
 {
     string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(json); 
     Properties.Resources.Json = bytes;
     Guardado = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal mira a ver si te puede ayudar esto: objetoJs.json es el nombre del archivo a guardará la serialización.
Para este código -> using System.Text.Json; (de .net5).
No se bien a lo que quieres llegar pero si es guardar el fichero ahí te dejo:

```
public static void SerializerAndSaveFile<T>(T Value)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true };
        string miJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Value, options);
        File.WriteAllText("objetoJs.json", miJson);
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ahora te paso este otro método con el cual consultas un nodo según el nombre de la propiedad a la que quieres acceder de un objeto:

```
public static string GetNode(string StringName)
    {
        var jsonBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("objetoJs.json");

        var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonBytes);

        var myString = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty(StringName).ToString(); // Get a string from a JsonElement


        return myString;
    }
```

Lo puedes verificar con -> `Console.WriteLine(JsonConverter.GetNode("NomPropiedad").ToString());`

De esta forma obtendras los valores de la propiedad requerida.

Saludos.....

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).